# Integral $\sqrt{1+|x|^2}^a exp(-|x|^2/4t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading a textbook on PDE and for the proof of certain theorem of existence the book claims one has the following inequality  with $a> 0$
$$t^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}(1+|x|^2)^{a/2} \exp(-|x|^2/4t) \ dx\leq C(1+|t|^2)^{a/4} $$
for all $t>0$. Does anyone have some hint for getting the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{t^{n/2}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|x|^2)^{a/2}\exp\left(-|x|^2/4t \right)\ dx =&\  \frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\int^\infty_0 \int_{|x|=r} (1+r^2)^{a/2}\exp(-r^2/4t)\ dS  dr\\
=&\ \frac{n\alpha(n)}{t^{n/2}} \int^\infty_0 (1+r^2)^{a/2}r^{n-1} \exp(-r^2/4t)\ dr
\end{align}
where $n\alpha(n)$ is the surface area of the $n$-sphere.

Then by $u$-substitution, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{n\alpha(n)}{t^{n/2}} \int^\infty_0 (1+r^2)^{a/2}r^{n-1} \exp(-r^2/4t)\ dr =&\  n\alpha(n)\int^\infty_0 (1+tu^2)^{a/2}u^{n-1}\exp(-u^2/2)\ du\\
\leq&\ n\alpha(n)(1+t)^{a/2} \int^\infty_0 (1+u^2)^{a/2}u^{n-1}\exp(-u^2/2) du.
\end{align}
Here we used the fact that $(1+tu^2) \leq (1+t)(1+u^2)$. And finally, we see that the integral converges which means
\begin{align}
t^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|x|^2)^{a/2}\exp\left(-|x|^2/4t \right)\ dx  \leq C (1+t)^{a/2}  \leq C' (1+t^2)^{a/4}.
\end{align}